# How much deep a Neural Network Required for 12 inputs of ranging from -5000 to 5000 in a3c Reinforcement Learning

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to use A3C with LSTM for an environment where states has 12 inputs ranging from -5000 to 5000.
I am using an LSTM layer of size 12 and then 2 fully connected hidden layers of size 256, then 1 fc for 3 action dim and 1 fc for 1 value function.
The reward is in range (-1,1).

However during initial training I am unable to get good results.

My question is- Is this Neural Network good enough for this kind of environment.

Below is the code for Actor Critic

```
class ActorCritic(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, params):
        super(ActorCritic, self).__init__()

        self.state_dim = params.state_dim
        self.action_space = params.action_dim
        self.hidden_size = params.hidden_size
        state_dim = params.state_dim
        self.lstm = nn.LSTMCell(state_dim, state_dim)
        self.lstm.bias_ih.data.fill_(0)
        self.lstm.bias_hh.data.fill_(0)
        lst = [state_dim]
        for i in range(params.layers):
            lst.append(params.hidden_size)
        
        self.hidden = nn.ModuleList()
        for k in range(len(lst)-1):
            self.hidden.append(nn.Linear(lst[k], lst[k+1]))
        for layer in self.hidden:
            layer.apply(init_weights)

        self.critic_linear = nn.Linear(params.hidden_size, 1)
        self.critic_linear.apply(init_weights)
        self.actor_linear = nn.Linear(params.hidden_size, self.action_space)
        self.actor_linear.apply(init_weights)
        self.train()

    def forward(self, inputs):
        inputs, (hx, cx) = inputs
        inputs = inputs.reshape(1,-1)
        hx, cx = self.lstm(inputs, (hx, cx))
        x = hx
        for layer in self.hidden:
            x = torch.tanh(layer(x))
        return self.critic_linear(x), self.actor_linear(x), (hx, cx)

class Params():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lr = 0.0001
        self.gamma = 0.99
        self.tau = 1.
        self.num_processes = os.cpu_count()
        self.state_dim = 12
        self.action_dim = 3
        self.hidden_size = 256
        self.layers = 2
        self.epochs = 10
        self.lstm_layers = 1
        self.lstm_size = self.state_dim
        self.num_steps = 20
        self.window = 50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have 12 inputs so make sure you dont use too many parameters, also try changing activation function.
i dont use Torch so i can not understand model architecture.
why your first layer is LSTM? is your data time series?
try using only Dense layer,

- 1 Dense only with 12 neurons and output layer
- 2 Dense Layers with 12 neurons each and output layer

As for activation function use leaky relu, since your data is -5000, or you can make your data positive only by adding 5000 to all data samples.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answer.
Yes my data is sequential.
Could you please let me know what should be the size of hidden layer if I use input dim of size 100

Comment: hidden layer normally have neurons equal to number of feature,  if you input has 100 samples and 12 features then use neurons between 10 to 20, because of 12 features.

Comment: if your data has 100 features then use neurons between 50 to 200, and see which perform better.
lower number of neuron, will be better but sometime you need more neuron for complex relation in data, but more neuron can cause overfitting.